# Example of an extension group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If you have short exact sequence

$$K \;\overset{f}{\rightarrow}\; G \;\overset{g}{\rightarrow}\; Q$$

(where $f$ is monomorphism and $g$ is epimorphism) then $G$ is said to be an extension of $K$ by $Q$.

**Question:**
Can you give an example of an extension of $K$ by $Q$ that dose not contain a subgroup isomorphic to $Q$ ?

**Note:** The question is edited with respect to the definition in the wikipedia.

Comment: What do you really mean by extension? is it semiderict product ?

Comment: it means: assume K and Q is groups. an extension of K by Q is group G that it is contain subgroup T that T isomorphic by K and G to T isomorphic by Q

Comment: If the sequence goes in this direction that's called «an extension of $Q$ by $K$», not the other way round.

Answer (score 2):

Let $G=Q_8$ be quaterian group and $K=\{1,-1\}=Z(Q_8)$.

Then $G/K\cong \mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2$.

Then you have an exact sequence $$K \;\overset{f}{\rightarrow}\; G \;\overset{g}{\rightarrow}\; Q$$

So $G$ is extension of $K$ by $Q=\mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2$ but $G$ does not contain any subgroup isomorphic to $Q$.

**explanation:** $Q_8$ have $6$ elements $\{i,j,k,-i,-j,-k\}$  with order $4$, so it has only one elments of order $2$ which shows that it can not have subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2$.

It is clear that $G/Z(G)$ is a group of order $4$. it can not be $\mathbb Z_4$ since if $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic then $G$ is abelian which is impossible. That is why we must have $G/Z(G)\cong \mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2$.